# What is the purpose of create method in Semantic React UI component

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I try to learn more about Semantic React UI. But I have a line code that I don't understand. Can someone explain the purpose of this method to me?

```js
Button.create = createShorthandFactory(Button, (value) => ({ content: value }))
```

Here is the codebase on GitHub: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/61a08733941fb60d6ff09f30c3e2fc13e40448da/src/elements/Button/Button.js#L309

Answer (score 0):

It sets up the method "create" on Button. You can follow the code in GitHub by hovering over something. Why do you need to know how the code behind it all works anyway?

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/61a08733941fb60d6ff09f30c3e2fc13e40448da/src/lib/factories.js#L23

Comment: I want to write a Button component on my own based on this. I still don't know the effect of the method "create". Is this overriding the "create" method of React Component or creating a new method "create" for Button component? How we can use this method? That is the mystery I want to discover